# Global.asax not firing on IIS 8.5 with NET Framework2.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, server, global-asax

We've got an aspnet app (framework 2.0) running on IIS7 server 2008 r2 and all is well.

I've been tasked with duplicating this app on Server 2102 r2 with IIS8.5. All appeared to have gone well, but when logging into the app, there was some odd behavior which stems from the Global.asax(or specifically the code behind) not running.

The app is running in an integrated app pool using NET v2.0 (exactly as it is on IIS7). To the best of my knowledge I've setup all settings as they are on the IIS7 server. Searching online suggested the following but neither have worked:
1) Adding 'runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"' into modules header in web.config.
2) Adding 'CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs"' to Global.asax and recompiling

Any further insight/have anything else I can try?

Comment: Refer http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization and in web. Config <system.webServer> <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="false"> <add initializationPage="/controller /action" /> </applicationInitialization> </system.webServer>.

Comment: VS can hook into app_start when the website is hosted in the VS development server.

Comment: Is it web site project or web app project? If it is web site project, you can not add codebehind cs file. Instead, just inline your C# code in Global.asax file.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions guys. Its a web app project, it works fine on IIS7 but not on IIS8.5. Vinutha, I've setup Application Initialization and modified web.config as you suggest but still nothing, although I'm a little confused as to how its supposed to work. what specifically goes in InitializationPage tag? Should I set this to "/Default.aspx" and expect it to find the global.asax? or should i create Intialise.aspx with initialisation code and use that? or just use "/Global.asax"? (i've actually tried all 3 but no luck).

Comment: @tonyelimpus Were you able to fix this issue?